# How to get 30 minutes time slots array in between two dates swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, time

for example:

```
startDate:- 20-08-2018 10:00 AM

endDate:- 20-08-2018 02:30 PM
```

> Output: ["10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM", "12:00PM",
>   "12:30 PM", "01:00 PM", "01:30 PM", "02:00 PM", "02:30 PM"]

```
var fromTime:Date = getFromTime
fromTime = fromTime.addingTimeInterval(-1800)

guard let toTime:Date  = timeFormat.date(from:endTime) else {
    return nil
}

var dateByAddingThirtyMinute : Date!
let timeinterval : TimeInterval = toTime.timeIntervalSince(fromTime)
let numberOfIntervals : Double = timeinterval / 3600;

var timeArrayAM = [String]()
var timeArrayPM = [String]()

for _ in stride(from: 0, to: Int(numberOfIntervals * 2), by: 1) {

    dateByAddingThirtyMinute = fromTime.addingTimeInterval(1800)
    fromTime = dateByAddingThirtyMinute

    if let dateString = dateByAddingThirtyMinute.format(with: "hh:mm a") as? String {

        // print("Time after 30 min = \(dateString)")

        if temp == 0 {

            let time = dateString
            guard let getStopTime = timeFormat.date(from: time) else {

                return nil
            }

            var stopTime = getStopTime

            var date = Date()
            date = date.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(advanceTimeInterval*60))
            let calendar = Calendar.current

            let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
            let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
            let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
            let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: stopTime)
            let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: stopTime)

            stopTime = calendar.date(bySetting: .year, value: year, of: stopTime)!
            stopTime = calendar.date(bySetting: .month, value: month, of: stopTime)!
            stopTime = calendar.date(bySetting: .day, value: day, of: stopTime)!
            stopTime = calendar.date(bySetting: .hour, value: hour, of: stopTime)!
            stopTime = calendar.date(bySetting: .minute, value: minute, of: stopTime)!

            let timeDifference = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: stopTime, to: date)

            // print_debug("************************************")
            // print(timeDifference.hour, timeDifference.minute)
            if timeDifference.hour! < 0 || timeDifference.minute! < 0 || (timeDifference.hour! == 0 && timeDifference.minute! == 0 ) {
                showFirstTime = dateString
                temp = 1
            }
            // print_debug("************************************")
        }
```

Comment: Loop between the start and end or every 30 minutes and add it to the list... why don't you put some effort in yourself and attempt so code. If you get a problem with the code, then bring it back here and show us it

Comment: I already did it, but my approach is taking so much line of code, I am asking here if there is any short approach any used for it before.

Comment: Always show the code you've got so far.

Comment: So post your code here then, and highlight your specific problem that you have with your code that you would like us to help you with

Comment: @musefan here I made it simple my problem, here I am giving u two dates, bt in my case I have two times "10:00 AM" "02:30 PM", so in this case, it is becoming so hard to get time slots array.

Comment: @VipulKumar: We don't help people who do not show any effort. Post your code, or you won't get any good help

Comment: see now, I added my code. if u find any good approach plz let me know

Comment: @VipulKumar: Ok, so now tell us what is wrong with your code? Does it work?

Comment: it works as I said, I wanted to know if u guys have some better approach to do it.

Comment: u can also suggest me, for two dates. bcz in that case I will make date according to time, but I want to reduce the code as much as I can

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this,

```
var array: [String] = []

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"

let formatter2 = DateFormatter()
formatter2.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

let startDate = "20-08-2018 10:00 AM"
let endDate = "20-08-2018 02:30 PM"

let date1 = formatter.date(from: startDate)
let date2 = formatter.date(from: endDate)

var i = 1
while true {
    let date = date1?.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(i*30*60))
    let string = formatter2.string(from: date!)

    if date! >= date2! {
        break;
    }

    i += 1
    array.append(string)
}
print(array)
```

Output of above is,

```
["10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "01:00 PM", "01:30 PM", "02:00 PM", "02:30 PM"]
```

Comment: this is right, but there can be also a condition when date is not in the exact multiple of 30minutes so make that check like this:-

Comment: if date >= endTime {
                break;
            }

Comment: @DilipTiwari, For 10 min just replace 30 with 10 under TimeInterval i.e, (i*10*60).

Comment: @DilipTiwari, Please generate a separate question for this with some more details.

Comment: I want to create the time slots like [09:00 - 09:30, 09:15 - 09:45, 09:30 - 10:30]. 30 minutes slots and 15 minutes gap.

Answer (score 1):

**Get 30 minute time slote between two dates.**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

             super.viewDidLoad()
     
             // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
             setTimeArray()
  }
 func setTimeArray(){
             var array: [String] = []
             let formatter = DateFormatter()
             formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
             let formatter2 = DateFormatter()
             formatter2.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
             let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
             dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
             let dt = Date()
             let nxtDt = dt.getNextDate()
             let Curdate = dt.DateToString(Formatter: "dd-MM-yyyy")
             let Nxtdate = nxtDt.DateToString(Formatter: "dd-MM-yyyy")
             let startDate = "\(Curdate) 10:00"
             let endDate = "\(Nxtdate) 00:00"
             
             let date1 = formatter.date(from: startDate)
             let date2 = formatter.date(from: endDate)
             let interval = 30
             let string = formatter2.string(from: date1!)
             array.append(string)
             var i = 1
             while true {
                 let date = date1?.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(i*interval!*60))
                 let string = formatter2.string(from: date!)
                 
                 if date! >= date2! {
                     break;
                 }
                 
                 i += 1
                 array.append(string)
             }
     }
```

**Output is:**

```
["10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "01:00 PM", "01:30 PM", "02:00 PM", "02:30 PM", "03:00 PM", "03:30 PM", "04:00 PM", "04:30 PM", "05:00 PM", "05:30 PM", "06:00 PM", "06:30 PM", "07:00 PM", "07:30 PM", "08:00 PM", "08:30 PM", "09:00 PM", "09:30 PM", "10:00 PM", "10:30 PM", "11:00 PM", "11:30 PM"]
```