# getting a nil value while calculating time slots swift

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

I'm following the solution in post [how to get 30 minutes time slots array in between two dates swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580344/how-to-get-30-minutes-time-slots-array-in-between-two-dates-swift) but I get a nil value on `date2`in my following function:

```
func calculateOpenTimeSlots() {

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
        let weekday = self.actualWeekday
        let openingTime = openingTimeArray[weekday!].openingTime
        let closingTime = openingTimeArray[weekday!].closingTime
        let date1 = formatter.date(from: openingTime)
        let date2 = formatter.date(from: closingTime)
        var i = 1
        timeSlotArray.removeAll()
        while true {
            let date = date1?.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(i*30*60))
            let string = formatter.string(from: date!)
            if date! >= date2! {break}
            i = i + 1
            timeSlotArray.append(string)
        }

    }
```

the array is:

```
var openingTimeArray: [(weekday: Int, openingTime: String, closingTime: String)] = [(weekday: 0, openingTime: "10:00", closingTime: "19:00"), (weekday: 1, openingTime: "10:00", closingTime: "19:00"), (weekday: 2, openingTime: "10:00", closingTime: "19:00"), (weekday: 3, openingTime: "10:00", closingTime: "19:00"), (weekday: 4, openingTime: "10:00", closingTime: "19:00"), (weekday: 5, openingTime: "10:00", closingTime: "19:00"), (weekday: 6, openingTime: "10:00", closingTime: "19:00"), (weekday: 7, openingTime: "10:00", closingTime: "19:00")]
```

`openingTime` and `closingTime`values are not nil and they are the right value, but on `date1`I get a complete date with hour being 1 hour early.
`date1` is 2000-01-01 09:00:00 UTC but I expected it to be 10:00.

I still don't master date formatter and I don't understand why I get a nil `date2`and a wrong `date1`. 
Any explanation to point me in the right direction will be very helpful as usual.
Many thanks

Comment: Be really careful with time zones when working with dates and date formatters. If you're getting an unexpected date from a date formatter, it might be because the date formatter does not have the same time zone as string you are using the create the date.

Comment: I think you wanted your formatter to recognize the am/pm designation, e.g. `formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was in the format declaration being `formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"`. I changed it to `formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"`and it now works as expected.
I had to add an append `timeSlotArray.append(openingTime)`before the `while`loop because the loop was not appending the first time slot starting at opening time, but I would like to rewrite the loop to take that into consideration. Any suggestion on how to achieve that?

```
func calculateOpenTimeSlots() {
         timeSlotArray.removeAll()

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
//        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        let weekday = self.actualWeekday
        let openingTime = openingTimeArray[weekday!].openingTime
        let closingTime = openingTimeArray[weekday!].closingTime
        let date1 = formatter.date(from: openingTime)
        timeSlotArray.append(openingTime)
        let date2 = formatter.date(from: closingTime)
        var i = 1

        while true {
            let date = date1?.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(i*30*60))
            let string = formatter.string(from: date!)
            if date! >= date2! {break}
            i = i + 1
            timeSlotArray.append(string)
        }
        print(timeSlotArray)

    }
```

Comment: You could do something like this:
`for date in stride(from: openingTime, to: closingTime, by: (30 * 60)) {
   // Add date to your timeSlotArray
}
`